# How to open an iframe link going through a VPN

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, vpn

I would like to embed on my website a german link which is free and open only to german public. If i open from another country i get "This show is not available in your country for legal reasons." 
Now if use a VPN in the other country i get access to the link. My question is:
Is there any way to embed an iframe passing his link through a VPN simply using javascript or jquery? 
Final result should be the filtered link visible on my website.
Thnx

Comment: You can't make _my_ browser use _your_ VPN, so the only solution would be to proxy those requests via a server that either uses the VPN, or is located in the "allowed" country to begin with.

Comment: _"which is free and open only to german public"_ - consider that you might get in legal trouble then, if you are circumventing that restriction not just for your own, private use, but to expose the content to other people ...

Comment: If the VPN provides the ability to use their service through a URL, then of course you can set the `src` attribute to that URL. Otherwise, you're out of luck. Doesn't matter how large the bounty is :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey actually the idea for the question came because i see some non regulated website that offer this kid of facility. I mean blocked links in USA for example are unblocked when they go through their domain like blockedsite.unblocker.com opens blockedsite.com when i access it through unblocker.com Is it possible to do this in much smaller scale :-) like just an iframe?

Comment: Setting up a static route to that IP through the VPN could work but would require manual setup from the user.

Answer (score 2):

Using a http proxy!

Limitation:

- No cookies
- Sessions are messed up
- Some website are proxy detection
- Self hosting only, regions limitation

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no proper technical way to get the information you want. If you invent some tests but those will have a very low correlation with the reality. So either you'll not catch those you want or you will have a larger number of false positives. Neither can be considered to make sense.

There is no difference between a request that has been routed through a VPN and one that has not. It's not practical to get an exhaustive list of VPN endpoint IP addresses, and many of them are shared with **non-VPN users** anyway.

Generating any kind of traffic backwards from Internet server in response to an incoming client (port scan or even a simple ping) is generally frowned upon. Or, in case of a port scan, it may be even worse for you, ex when the client lives behind a central corporate firewall, the worst of which is when the client comes from behind the central government network firewall pool...

Comment: Sorry, this does not even remotely address the question.

Comment: @FishSaidNo please read question again...

Comment: Again, this answer does not even remotely address the question.

Comment: @FishSaidNo if you understand the question please now read the answer again! and why aren't you post the answer here...